# Mongoose multiple optional 'and' conditions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to filter a collection with 3 optional 'and' conditions.

Here is my model:

```
const Company = mongoose.model(
  'Company',
  new Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    sectors: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sector' }],
    industries: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Industry' }],
    countries: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Country' }],   
  })
```

And my component:

```
const getCompanies = (skip, limit, filter) =>
  Company.find({
    ...filter.countries && { countries: filter.countries },
    ...filter.sectors && { sectors: filter.sectors },
    ...filter.industries && { industries: filter.industries },
 })
.skip(skip)
.limit(limit)
.sort({ date: -1 })
.populate('countries')
.populate('sectors')
.populate('industries');


const getAll = async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const countries = req.query.country;
  const sectors = req.query.sector;
  const industries = req.query.industry;
  const skip = parseInt(req.query.skip, 10);
  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 10);
  const filter = {
    ...countries && { countries },
    ...sectors && { sectors },
    ...industries && { industries },
  };
  const result = await getCompanies(skip, limit, filter);
  return res.status(200).json(result);
} catch (e) {
  return res.status(500).send({ message: (e.message) });
}
};
```

This is working when the filter is empty, but when there is one or more items in the filter, I get an empty array.

If I hard code data in getCompanies like so:

```
Company.find({
  countries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c77e',
  sectors: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c754',
  industries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c7ad',
})
```

or :

```
Company.find({
  countries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c77e'
})
```

I get the data I want.

I also tried to console.log the filter in getCompanies to make sure the data was correct, and I get this if all fields are requested:

```
{
  countries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c77e',
  sectors: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c754',
  industries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c7ad',
}
```

and this for just one:

```
{ countries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c77e' }
```

So it seems fine to me.

I also tried using '$and' like so:

```
Company.find({ $and: [
    { ...filter.countries && { countries: filter.countries } },
    { ...filter.sectors && { sectors: filter.sectors } },
    { ...filter.industries && {industries: filter.industries } },
  ],
  })
```

or using '$in':

```
Company.find({
    ...filter.countries && { countries: { $in: filter.countries } },
    ...filter.sectors && { sectors: { $in: filter.sectors } },
    ...filter.industries && { industries: { $in: filter.industries } },
  })
```

But no luck either.

Here is a sample URL:

```
GET /api/internal/member/get?skip=12&limit=6&country=5d5e913e20c01070fef5c77e&sector=&industry=
```

I have found some other threads with questions somewhat similar to mine, but they were to different to help me solve my case.

Looking forward to your helpful advice.

Comment: Hey there! Can you share a sample URL(along with the query params) that you are using to access this endpoint?

Comment: I doubt if you're getting any data even when you hardcode like this :: `Company.find({
  countries: '5d5e913e20c01070fef5c77e'
})` Cause in your DB if these values are of type `ObjectId()` then passing string in input doesn't match anything, So convert strings to ObjectId() & pass in input like this `const mongoose = require('mongoose');
{...filter.countries && { countries: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(filter.countries) }`, If they're array of string then iterate, convert & then pass in..

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have edited my post with a sample URL. @whoami I have tried again hardcoding the data, and it works. I also tried your solution and I'm still getting an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Turns out I was not clearing the data in the frontend at each change, which caused an issue with the skip/limit fields.

I also changed the find as advised by @whoami like so:

```
Company.find({ $and: [
    {
      ...filter.countries && { countries: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(filter.countries)] } },
      ...filter.sectors && { sectors: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(filter.sectors)] } },
      ...filter.sdgs && { sdgs: { $in: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId(filter.sdgs)] } },
    }
  ],
  })
```